# Console logging on ember js

Tags: ember.js, console

I would just like to ask why is it that when you print out on the console on ember it gives you a string? but if you typeof on it, it gives you a function?

```
ex. sample = Ember.Route.extend();

console.log(sample); // prints (subclass of Ember.Route)

console.log(typeof sample); // function
```

Can someone explain this please? Aside with their documentation that is hard to grasp. It's really hard to debug on ember, even with ember inspector. Is there any tool or way to properly debug ember.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In terms of Ember debugging, you probably already read this: https://guides.emberjs.com/release/configuring-ember/debugging/

There is a couple of great feature, what you can turn on during development, to get more information, what's happening under the hood.

**You can insert in your app.js:**

```
var App = Ember.Application.extend({
  LOG_TRANSITIONS_INTERNAL:  true,
  LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION:     true,
  LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS:          true,
  LOG_RESOLVER:              true,
});

Ember.run.backburner.DEBUG            = true;
Ember.ENV.RAISE_ON_DEPRECATION        = true;
Ember.LOG_STACKTRACE_ON_DEPRECATION   = true;
Ember.LOG_BINDINGS                    = true;
Ember.RSVP.on('error', function(error) {
  Ember.Logger.assert(false, error);
});
```

**You can stop your code** if you write `debugger` in your code. I use it quite often to figure out what's happening there.

In terms of your question, if you extend an Ember class it basically create a new function, but behave as a subclass of extended class. You can check what's happening there: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.7.0/packages/ember-runtime/lib/system/core_object.js#L536-L556

When you run your Ember app, your app gonna be wrapped in a **container**, so if you need access to properties or variables, you have to use this - assume your app name is 'App':

```
App.__container__.lookup("controller:application").get("currentRouteName")
App.__container__.lookup("controller:application").get("currentPath")
App.__container__.lookup("controller:application").get("model")
```

It is take a while to understand how could you debug your ember app, but worth to learn and invest more time in it, because will be quite handy later.

If you have any question, don't hesitate to comment and we can solve it.

**About debugger;**

It is like a breakpoint, you can stop the code. "Inspect element"/"Developer Tool" have to be open in Chrome. Little example here: http://jsbin.com/cugetoxoyira/45

Source code: http://jsbin.com/cugetoxoyira/45/edit
In Line 18, there is a `debugger;` , so you can check in your console what is in controller or in model params. You have to type in only `controller` in your Console in Developer Tool of Chrome.

Comment: I see, thanks. So there are more options to debug. Can you put some details what are those for if you don't mind?

As I can see here https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.7.0/packages/ember-runtime/lib/system/core_object.js#L536-L556 it returns an object that's why we can access some properties onto it, but why typingOf it prints a function? I don't quite get it.

putting `debuggger` on code? is this something like a breakpoint? or?

Yes, it really takes time to fully understand well ember, I am investing my time and effort on this. Hope it will pay (worry)

Comment: That's because ember overrides toString method for that object. `var fun = function () {}; /* fun - 'function', typeof fun - 'function' */ fun.toString = function() { return 'any string'; } /* fun - 'any string', typeof fun - 'function'*/`

Comment: I extended my answer with debugger; and you can see a little example in jsbin.com as well... JSBin is a great website to learn and play with snippets... so if you would like to solve some simple problem, but not really works, you can share with us as well.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the explanations and tips. It's great. Now I can finally see what was going on inside of it. :) cheers!

Comment: P.S. Irrelevant to this topic, do you have some diagram or flow for sequences on ember? (Maybe I should create a new topic for this?no?). 

like what will be called first? and next, etc..

if you don't have some diagram maybe some pseudo code with explanations? :) Thanks again!

Comment: One of the most important is your path's Route file. You can find loats of details here: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html
Hooks: beforeModel -> Model -> afterModel -> setupController -> renderTemplate

Comment: Balint has a quite great free screencast series, you should check them: http://balinterdi.com/ and you can find a loads of useful posts as well.

Comment: I see, I'll check on this http://balinterdi.com/. Why is the learning curve of emberjs is hard to grasp? Even their documentation is not that good. Hmmm, I believe of the saying that "if you can't explain it well, you don't understand it fully" lol, anyway, thank you for the quick response and the screencast.

Comment: The learning curve is not soo steep anymore. Check this tutorial: http://yoember.com ;)

Comment: The ember URL now 404s, I'm guessing it should now point to https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/configuring-ember/debugging/ but I'm not 100% sure

Answer (score 3):

Just use `{{log "This is logged" foo "And so is this"}}`

Reference: http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html