# Ember JS how to implement a normal ES6 class

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm new to Ember and I'm having an issue with understanding exactly where "reusable" code should go. From what I've found so far, it sounds like this is supposed to be a utility? The only issue I have no idea how to include the class (or any reusable methods) into the controller.

Here's what I'm after

Example class (where would this go?):

```
'use strict'

class Person{
    constructor(name, age){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    getPerson(){
        return "My name is " + this.name + " and I'm " + this.age + " years old";
    }
}
```

/app/routes/index.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    beforeModel(){
        this.replaceWith('rentals');
    }
});

/* How would I include the class so I could call the below??
    var person1 = new Person('Bob', '15');
    var person2 = new Person('Kevin', '41');
    console.log(person1.getPerson());
    console.log(person2.getPerson());
*/
```

Comment: why you use es6 class definition, you can use Ember.Object instead, computed properties will be available

Comment: @Dart For the reason mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26412628/console-logging-on-ember-js it's much easier to debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a separate file for your `Person` class and import it where you need it. Then you can work with your class as you normally would:

```
// /app/util/Person.js

export default class Person{
    constructor(name, age){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    getPerson(){
        return "My name is " + this.name + " and I'm " + this.age + " years old";
    }
}


// /app/routes/index.js

import Ember from 'ember';
import Person from '../util/Person';

// ...

const person1 = new Person('Bob', '15');

// ...
```